# How to remove reflections from an image in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, product-photography

How can I fix the parts that contain light reflections in the following image using Photoshop:
[image]

Comment: This is not overexposure, it looks like it is just reflections from your lighting on the product surface.  To remove them you want to make them darker and bluer so they look more like the surrounding parts of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to use the dodge and burn tool. This is a destructive modification so you first need to duplicate the layer. Select the burn tool, a soft edge brush and set the Range to midtones and exposure to around 5% and darken the area gradually. If you want to work non-destructively, you can paint black on a layer above set to soft light blend mode and knock the opacity to something like 10%.